# Запрос в Telegram боте

Tags: telegram, telebot

При написании бота в Телеграм с помощью PyTelegramBotAPI столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Имеется функция для поиска видео на Youtube. Функция принимает в себя аргументом ключевое слово\фразу для поиска. И возвращает список ссылок.
Как реализовать это в боте так, что бы бот при использовании прописанной команды (скажем /find_video) запрашивал слово\фразу - аргумент для функции и возвращал список ссылок?
Добился пока только следующего - аргумент прописан в коде
- аргумент запрашивается и вводится непосредственно в PyCharm
В обоих случаях, бот отправит ссылку на нужное видео, но только 1. Как вывести списком несколько ссылок?

Вот сама функция:

```
def findvideo(x):
    data1 = []
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=' + quote(x)
    links = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('cp1251', errors='ignore')
    match = re.findall("\?v\=(.+?)\"", links)
    if not (match is None):
        for i in match:
            if (len(i) < 25):
                data1.append(i)
    data1 = dict(zip(data1, data1)).values()
    data2 = []
    for y in data1:
        data2.append('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + y)
    return data2
```

А вот тестовые хендлеры в боте:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["find_video"])
def cmd_find_video(message):
    x = input('Введите запрос: ')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, findvideo(x))   # Запрос вводится в PyCharm

@bot.message_handler(commands=["find_video"])
def cmd_find_video(message):
    x = input('ключевоеслово\фраза\для поиска')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, findvideo(x))   # Статичный аргумент для функции
```

Answer (score 1):

```
почему `input()` то?

@bot.message_handler(commands=["find_video"])
def find_video(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите запрос: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, find_video_2)


def find_video_2(message):
    query = findvideo(message.text.lower())
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '{}'.format(query))
```